# What is the easiest way to extend Java syntax (hygienic macros)

Tags: java, syntax, macros, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a way to extend java syntax, basically I want to implement lispish "macro" system where I can have a preprocessor that will modify AST in compile-time.

What is the easiest way to plug in java compiler so that I can modify AST based on my personal syntax extensions so that compiler will still be able to catch class cast exceptions and so on. I would also like to read AST and modify it based on what is found. Basically I want to have hygienic macros with java.

I know about [project lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) but that is almost only library/project that I'm aware of that actually does extend AST but what I want to do is a bit more complex.

Why I want to do this? I want to try if it's possible add a pattern matching syntax, type inference, really readable function syntax and so on with Java.

Comment: You can borrow some ideas from here: http://www.chrisseaton.com/katahdin/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the COTS Java compiler will cooperate with you attempting to extend its syntax.   And I don't think it will regenerate source code, but then you may not care if you only want to compile programs after expanding your macros.

If you want to extend the grammar, you probably as a minimum to to get a parser generator, the grammer for Java, and start hacking away.   [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) would do, and I believe it has a Java grammar available.  You'll need to build a prettyprinter to regenerate macro-resolved code to feed to a compiler; I don't think ANTLR offers this off the shelf.

As a practical matter, I suspect you will want symbol table information that the hygenic macros can inspect and adjust as they expand.  In that case, you might get an open source Java compiler ([Jikes](http://jikes.sourceforge.net)) and hack that up.  It may be the case that such open source compilers are not up to the latest Java standards.

If want something reasonably up to date, that parses Java, will let you hack at the grammar, and has full symbol table support, you might consider our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html).   DMS provides parsing, tree building, symbol table construction, procedural access/modification to the AST, prettyprinting to regenerate source, and source-to-source transformations for what grammar you define to DMS (including your hygenic macros, if you add their syntax to the Java grammar).

Comment: I think openjdk is now the official java 7 reference implementation so yes, I could hack that but I'm trying to found even easier way (if it exists) or more portable solution. I'll check DMS, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Mikkom: Does openJDK give you the compiler sources?  If so, that's an answer.

Comment: Yes, OpenJDK is GPL. I was going to comment on "…open source compilers not up to the latest Java standards…" … I'm actually not aware of any closed-source Java compilers that are (although I haven't gone looking).

Comment: Yes that is one solution but I'm trying to find a way that wouldn't require me to fork the compiler if possible.

Comment: @mikkom: you're not going to get a choice about forking the grammar, and the supporting basic analysis that build symbol tables. I agree, you sure don't want to fork the code generation end.

Comment: yes of course I have to fork the grammar but what I meant is I would like to use an existing tool base if possible. I found an interesting candidate but this would require to use existing java grammar (or basically twist it by using some strange class names etc)  so I'm now trying to see if this is enough for me (basically if I can use annotations although the syntax is not very nice at all). Here is an example of modifying all variables to final with javac api http://code.google.com/p/immutablej/source/browse/trunk/src/org/immutablej/immuter/Processor.java

Comment: @mikkom: With a source-to-source transformation system, you can typically write a rule like "\declaration \identifier; => final \declaration \identifier;" to achieve your finalize-everything example. That's pretty easy compared to hacking the AST.  No, it isn't quite *that* easy, but it is much easier to do complex things.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse IDE you could look into the [Eclipse Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) project.

It supports extending Java with custom macros via [active annotations](https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/204_activeannotations.html).